# Zoom in and out ImageView leaves blank areas and crops image

Tags: android, android-imageview

I am resizing image in ImageView, but after resize the ImageView size is remaining the same so if I zooming out I see black areas, and if I zoom in the image is cropped. How can I auto fit the size of ImageView to wrap my image? The problem is the image remains also the same size. My image located in custom scroll view that can scroll X and Y direcrion. Please DO NOT refer me to ImageView zoom examples, because I seen them.

```
ImageView map = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewMap);
Bitmap mapIm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.myMap);
map.setImageBitmap(mapIm); 
final Matrix zoommatrix = new Matrix();

    zoomOut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

             float[] centerpoint = {map.getWidth()/2.0f, map.getHeight()/2.0f};

             zoommatrix.postScale(0.9f, 0.9f, centerpoint[0], centerpoint[1]);
             map.setImageMatrix(zoommatrix);

        }
    });

    zoomIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

             float[] centerpoint = {map.getWidth()/2.0f, map.getHeight()/2.0f};

             zoommatrix.postScale(1.1f, 1.1f, centerpoint[0], centerpoint[1]);
             map.setImageMatrix(zoommatrix);


             Log.d(TAG, "Width: "+map.getWidth()+" Height: "+map.getHeight()); //always the same
             Log.d(TAG, "Width: "+mapIm.getWidth()+" Height: "+mapIm.getHeight()); //always the same


        }
    });
```

Comment: You want the ImageView container to resize, how is it defined in your layout xml?  Is it set to wrap_content or something else?

Comment: Yes, wrap_content. The image size is not changed, that is why wrap content does not affect.

Answer (score 0):

Try v.invalidate() after image processing